# Starting with Compass and Sass

Tags: css, compass-sass, compass

i wanted to ask, how can i continue working on existing project, while having no experience on compass/sass used here?

I always use Grunt and Less, but now i have to face Compass and Sass.

Here, i created screenshot of files structure.

My problem is, how setup system to get this all work. For example i see this code in compass/scss/style.scss:

```
@import "compass";
@import "bootstrap";
@import "mixins";
@import "defaults";
@import "layouts/forms";
@import "layouts/header-footer";
@import "layouts/home";
```

For example, i see @import compass, but there is no directory like this, and i dont know how can i attach - install compass, to get this work.
[image]

And another question, with grunt all i needed, was gruntfile configured, then i just type "grunt observe", and all changes in less files was converted to one css file.

But here, i can't find starting point. I have installed Ruby, and i have tried various commands in command line, but nothing works.

For example, from compass page, i have tried :

```
$ cd /path/to/project
$ compass watch
```

But this does nothing, just show some info in command line, that compass is watching for changes...

So in general, how to continue this project without installed components to work with ?

Comment: command compass watch in /path/to/project was solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Using Sass and Compass,
You are required to Install `Ruby`, `sass` and `compass`,
Then move to the project folder path where the `config.rb` file lies,
Then run the `compass watch` here
you can see like the following on your terminal / bash / command prompt
`>>> Compass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to Stop.`
After this If there is no css file created, You have to simply make some changes on one of the scss files or partial files(_filename) that you have imported to `style.scss`.

The link will guide you to proper installation and creating project folder setting up.
http://compass-style.org/install/